# How can i switch to another user account from an admin account

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have a user table in which i have an Admin account and some other normal users accounts.

I want to do all activities which for a particular user.  It should act like that activity done by same user.

Can somebody tell me how can i switch to another account from Admin account
without login to that account.

Currently i use passport authentication.(passport-local)

Here is my  code

```
app.get('/secure/group/login', function(req,res,next) {
        passport.authenticate('local',function(err,user,info) {
            console.log("error is "+err);
            req.logIn('tessAccount',function(err) {
                    console.log("Weer" +err);

            });
            console.log("dd");

        })(req,res,next);
    });

    });
```

and passport code

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport) {
    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.token);
    });


passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
  function(token, done) {
      user.tokenExist(token, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                 else {
                    return done(null, user, { scope: 'all' });
                }
      });
  }
));
    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(accessToken, done) {
        user.getUserByAccessToken(accessToken, function(err, dbUser) {
            if (err) {
                done(err);
            } else {
                done(null, dbUser[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'
    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            user.emailExists(email, function(err, exists) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                else if (exists) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: req.flash('loginMessage')
                    });
                } else {
                    req.userDetails.status = 0;
                    req.userDetails.token = md5.digest_s(req.userDetails.email + new Date());
                    req.userDetails.userImage = config.user.image;

                    user.register(req.userDetails, function(err, newUser) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        else {
                            /*Get user Shared article if exist start*/
                            getSharedArticlesOfnewlyuserIfExist(email, newUser.insertId);
                            /*Get user Shared article if exist end*/

                            req.userDetails.id = newUser.insertId;
                            return done(err, req.userDetails);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }));

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {

            // callback with email and password from our form
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            user.matchPassword({
                email: email,
                password: password
            }, function(err, newUser) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                // if no user is found, return the message
                if (newUser.length > 0) {
                    var user = {
                        id: newUser[0].user_id,
                        email: newUser[0].email_id,
                        token: newUser[0].user_access_token
                    };
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Incorrect username or password.'
                    }); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                }

            });

        }));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
User.findOne({ username: 'Myusername' }, function(err, user) {
    req.logIn(user, function(err){});
});
```

This worked for me to log into an account without using password, it switches from my admin account to an user account.

Actually I'm using passport.js and mongoose

Comment: i am getting this error
[Error: Failed to serialize user into session]

Comment: Did you implement
`passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});` ?

Comment: yes, i have added this. i have added some code.  into my question

Comment: By the way i am using mysql.

Comment: I never used passport with mysql but I think that you should try replacing `req.logIn('tessAccount',function(err) {
                    console.log("Weer" +err);` with `req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                    console.log("Weer" +err);` because you're associating a string to req.user instead of an object

Comment: I also tried req.logIn(user, function(err) { console.log("Weer" +err); but its not working.

Comment: Can you try to query an user, then executing your `req.logIn()` outside of `passport.authenticate()` ?